# when list of data(data table) scroll fiished

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

when I try to top to bottom,
The screen not scroll when the list(data table) finshed.

what I needs is when the Ranking list(this is in the below gif) scroll finished my screen should be scroll

[image]

```
Row(
        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start,
        children: [
          Expanded(
            child: SingleChildScrollView(
              scrollDirection: Axis.vertical,
              child: DataTable(
                 
                  columns: const <DataColumn>[
                    DataColumn(
                        label: Text('Name/vol',
                            style:
                                TextStyle(fontSize: 15, color: Colors.grey))),
                    DataColumn(
                        label: Text('Last Price',
                            style:
                                TextStyle(fontSize: 15, color: Colors.grey))),
                    DataColumn(
                        label: Text('24h Chg %',
                            style:
                                TextStyle(fontSize: 15, color: Colors.grey))),
                  ], 
                  dataRowHeight: 65, 
                  
                  rows: row()),
            ),
          ),
        ],
      ),
```

Comment: Try BouncingScrollPhysics()

Comment: @AR I used DataTable widget not a ListView that the case?

Comment: As I can see in your code you have used singlechildscrollView, You can use physics on it.

Comment: I have used that but the upper body not scrolling